# Listing field values from JSON using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

With respect to question [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212342/populating-select-with-json-in-angularjs-with-ng-options) , even I was looking some thing like that only . But it has to eliminate repeating values. Can any one please help me in this.

FOR example `$scope.notes=[{"id":"id1", "text":"text1"}, {"id":"id2", "text":"text2"}, {"id":"id2", "text":"text1"}];` This will list all the "**text values**" from **notes** JSON data , but it will repeat **text1** value twice. Can we make it to display only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this.

```
 <div ng-model="modelName" ng-repeat="note in notes | unique:'text'">
    <div>{{note.text}}</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I will try now

Comment: Hi .. To use **unique** , do we need to include **angular-filter.min.js** in our application

Comment: Thank you for your help. Code is working fine. But we have to use **angular-filter.min.js**.  Without this I tried , it didnt work.

Comment: @naik3 :  If my solution worked for you, you can consider to accept and upvote too.